# Can't search R!

Tags: support, search

Why I can't search [R](http://www.r-project.org/)?
It shows [a strange page](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=r)!

Comment: What, you got questions about pirates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to search for the tag `r` so type in the search box `[r]` There is a difference between the tag `r` and the content `r`

Comment: The man is right, see the results: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]